# From cmd.exe script, how can I schedule a task to run on next boot (and never again)?

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd, scheduled-tasks

As part of a very simple `cmd.exe` install script, I need to run a program the next time the machine reboots. I don't want it to run after that (it's a one-shot configuration tool).

The program will actually be another `cmd.exe` script but any example should do since I can run cmd /c on the script itself.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Which Windows versions does it have to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` key

This [VB script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/5d8dbd96-0614-4a7a-bc59-7fae7d15262f) could help. Extract:

```
workfile      = ifile.ReadLine
strcomputer   = ucase(left(workfile,instr(workfile,",")-1))
Set oReg      = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strcomputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

if err.number <> 0 then
 ofile.WriteLine "[" & now() & "] " & strcomputer & " will NOT run once. Failed to set runonce install with error: " & Err.Number & "/" & left(Err.Description,17) 
else
 sKeyPathEnv      = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
 sValueName       = "Set_RunOnce"
 sKeyPath     = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
 sValueName       = "SystemRoot"

 oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKLM, sKeyPath, sValueName, sSystemRoot
 oReg.SetStringValue HKLM, sKeyPathEnv, "Set_RunOnce", vRunOnce

 if Err.Number <> 0 then
  ofile.WriteLine "[" & now() & "] " & strcomputer & " will NOT run once. Failed to set runonce install with error: " & Err.Number & "/" & left(Err.Description,17) 
 else
  ofile.WriteLine "[" & now() & "] " & strcomputer & " will run once via runonce at next reboot. "
 end if
end if
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use REG.EXE to accomplish the same thing. I usually prefer REG.EXE to incurring the extra mind-boggle of a scripting language.

Comment: @Krim: true, the scripting language here only add log and error management. If you do not need that extra level, reg.exe is enough.

Comment: Winner by default, I guess :-) No, actually it's a good answer, and we *do* need error handling so I'll probably do it in VBScript. Thanks, VonC.